# Where to place custom packages that are being developed in github?

Tags: github, version-control

I want to get started developing my own packages. I am also adding version control via Github. I mainly develop on my Mac and a Windows laptop, but there is potential for me to develop on other machines down the line. My IDE of choice is PyCharm. I need to figure out where to place my packages both on Github and on my local machines so that my packages are always in sync regardless of where I am developing. Help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's clarify that **git** is the version control system, and **Github** is a platform for hosting **git** repositories (there are many other platforms aside from Github). You use **git** commands to manage your codes, and **Github** is where you store a copy of your codes.

By adding version control and putting a copy on Github, you've already taken the first step in managing your codes on different machines. All you need to do is to make sure the codes on Github is *always* the latest updated or maintained version.

Here's a sample workflow:

1. On machine 1 (Mac), *clone* a copy of the Github repo
2. Develop on machine 1
3. When you are satisfied with your changes, *push* your codes from machine 1 to Github
4. On machine 2 (Windows), *clone* a copy of the Github repo
5. Develop on machine 2
6. When you are satisfied with your changes, *push* your codes from machine 2 to Github
7. On machine 1, do a *fetch* to check for updates to the code
8. If there are updates, *pull* those changes to machine 1
9. Again, when done making changes, *push* them from machine 1 to Github
10. On machine 2 again, *fetch* and *pull* changes
11. Repeat this *fetch*-*pull*-*push*- cycle for all machines

Basically, you'll need to make sure that on wherever machine you are, when you are done, you should always *push* those changes to the remote (Github). So that other machines, can *fetch* and *pull* those changes and continue where you left off.

---

**UPDATE** (based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562187/where-to-place-custom-packages-that-are-being-developed-in-github/58584303?noredirect=1#comment103509666_58584303)):

Once you've got the workflow for your package source codes, next is to package them like any other regular Python package and install them to your site-packages (either directly for your system or preferably in a virtual environment).

I recommend taking a look at the Python docs on [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects) which uses [setuptools](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#setuptools) to make your package compatible with `pip`.

Here's a sample workflow:

1. `git clone <mypackage@github.com>`  # or `git pull` if you already cloned it before
2. `cd mypackage`
3. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. `pip install -e .` or `pip install --user -e .`

That last step will install your package to your *site-packages* folder, like any other `pip`-compatible package (assuming you've setup your *setup.py* file properly). If you are using virtual environments, you'll have to activate the virtual env first, then install your package there.

If you are not going to do any modification on the source code, and you just want to install the package on a specific machine, then you can also [specify the Github URL to pip](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs):

> ```
> $ pip install -e git+https://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=SomeProject # from git
> ```

Lastly, if you are planning to upload this package to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/), check out the docs on [Uploading the distribution archives](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-the-distribution-archives). This just adds an extra step to your workflow of uploading your package to PyPi and then doing `pip install` from there next time.

Comment: thank you for providing an explanation of the differences between git and Github. One last thing( I think). Is it wise to clone a copy of my Github repo to my site-packages directory i.e `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages` (on windows) if I am developing a package that I want to import on multiple modules? If I have multiple virtual environments, will I need to clone my repository to each environment?

Comment: @adamz88 No, don't do that. If you want to put your package in *site-package* then you have to do it like for any other Python package: using `pip install`. I updated my answer to explain. Basically you'll have to learn how to [package Python projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). There's quite a lot of steps to learn, but then afterwards, you can do `pip install .` or `pip install --user .` to put it in your site-packages folder.